# How to force a network error during SSIS execution?

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, networking, error-handling, ssis

I've had long running jobs fail due to network error (specific error below) while writing to a an endpoint via a OLE DB Destination.

I want to implement error handling regarding this network error and subsequently test the error.

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to throw an SSIS package error of a certain type at a predetermined time to test. Should be possible with MS's big push towards "Dev Ops".

There are some hacky ways I can imagine doing it like a script task, but I'm wondering if there is any built-in framework I'm just not aware of.

> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for
>   SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description:
>   "[DBNETLIB][ConnectionWrite (send()).]General network error. Check
>   your network documentation.".

There is not much on MSDN regarding throwing specific errors to test your exception handling processes.

- [Exception Handling for connection errors-SSIS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ce668796-4c45-4799-8521-ce5fb1feefbf/exception-handling-for-connection-errorsssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Comment: If you are really doing unit-testing (as your tags seem to imply) you would mock your functions that access the network.  However, the way you describe how you think about doing it seem to indicate you are rather planning to do integration-testing.  Could you clarify what you are intending to do, and, ideally, also share some code (code to be tested and test code)?

Comment: sure I can later... there is not much code since it's a foreach on a blob iterable which is being processed and then inserted into a staging table. When I ran the loop to test it, it failed after a couple hours due to a network error. The code reviewer wanted me to error handle for that network error so my first step was wonder if there is an error I can throw somehow... I've never thrown an error intentionally in SSIS.

Comment: I see - however, in unit-testing you would not have SSIS throw the error.  Instead, you would set up some mock and 'simulate' the error from there.  Your code that does the error handling should not see a difference, and you have more freedom for testing, because your test can control the mock's behaviour.  However, if you show your code a more specific advice is possible.